# Hack: Azure WebJobs connect to Storage Emulator

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-storage-emulator

I understand that there is no direct way yet to be able use the Storage Emulator to build and test my WebJobs as its not supported in the pre released version of WebJobs SDK, but is there some way to HACK that SDK to be able to try this out?

I don't want to connect to Azure account while I am building and testing my sample projects. So looking to see if  there is any kind of workaround.

Regards
Kiran

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry Kiran, that is not possible. The emulator does not support all the features that WebJobs SDK require to run - that's why we don't allow it.

Comment: May be a wrong question, but i'll ask any way. Do you happen to know if this will change any time soon?

Comment: The emulator does not support blog logs and it would not be possible to emulate blog triggers. We don't control the SDK emulator, so I cannot tell you if that feature will be available in the future or not.

Answer (score 1):

As of the `2.0.0-alpha-10307` nightly build on [MyGet](https://www.myget.org/gallery/azure-appservice) you can run WebJobs against the storage emulator. Not only can you read data from it, but you can also use the storage triggers as well.

The discussion around this being implemented can be found in [GitHub issue #53](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/53).

Since this is a pre-release and experimental there may be features that don't work or don't work as expected just yet. You'll need to test it for yourself and report any issues on GitHub. So far in my own experience it works fine with Queue Triggers.

**Update:** This is now available on NuGet in the [2.0.0-beta1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs/2.0.0-beta1) prerelease